# Ключ присутствует в Dictionary, но при получении значения выдает KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, строки

У меня есть следующий код:

```
             int StartNumber = 0;
             Dictionary<string, string> pboxcID = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //Заполняем массив 
            for (int i = 0; i <= sCIDs.Length - 1; i++)
            {                   
                pboxcID.Add("File" + (i + StartNumber), sCIDs[i]);
            }
             string picID = "";
             picID = pboxcID[cID]; - cID переменная, есть в Dictionary (опять же из отладчика)
```

И на строке поиска значения по ключу вылетает исключение: KeyNotFoundException. Ключ есть в Dictionary, переменная равна этому ключу, но значение не могу получить из-за исключения. Есть идеи, товарищи?

UPD: скриншоты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: для VlaD

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76805/discussion-on-question-by-oleg-junior----dictionary---).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> pboxcID = 
  new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

if (pboxcID.ContainsKey(cID))
  picID = pboxcID[cID];
```

Буквы "C" и/или "а" в ключах словаря и в переменной из разных алфавитов.

Comment: к сожалению, не работает

Comment: @OlegJunior Маленький гномик высунулся из компьютера и сказал "Не работает"?

Comment: просто дальше из-за не получения значения моя программа падает

Comment: @OlegJunior Вы думаете, что ключ есть в словаре, а гномик уверен, что его там нет. Кто из вас прав?

Comment: Ваш стёб надо мной, конечно, хорошо, но не до этого

Comment: @OlegJunior Нет в словаре ключа с значением, по которому Вы пытаетесь получить строку. Выведите все ключи из словаря, выведите значение переменной `cID` и Вы в этом убедитесь.

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, выше

Comment: @OlegJunior Прекрасно. Буквы "а" в ключах словаря и в переменной из разных алфавитов.

Comment: каким образом это может быть, когда не я ввожу значения, а программа?

Comment: @OlegJunior кхм, кхм, какая программа? секретная?

Comment: А почему в словарь добавляется File0, а в отладчике Card0? Поиграйтесь с окном интерпретации